# Como retornar strings que estão em formato de data em crescente no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, data

Eu peguei um `long` e gravei no banco com este formato `SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` que é uma *string* e agora preciso organizar as datas. Tentei usar este comando mas ele vem em ordem decrescente `ORDER BY date (data_coleta)` e o 'ASC' não funcionou neste caso.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Grave no formato `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")`. O valor mais significativo - o ano - deve vir antes e o menos significativo - o dia - deve vir no final. É matemática básica para tornar algo crescente.

O formato que está no banco de dados independe de qualquer formato que será usado na apresentação. Se fosse outro banco de dados que tem um tipo `date`, ele não estaria em formato algum que interessa para qualquer aplicação.

No caso do SQLite, que não tem este tipo, você tem que cuidar disto na mão.

Valor gravado e formato de apresentação são coisas distintas. Grave no formato que precisa no banco de dados e adapte o dado sempre que for apresentá-lo.

Comment: é que no meu caso eu tenho que colocar no formato Brasileiro mesmo, não tem jeito.

Comment: Não tem que colocar. O formato que está no banco de dados independe de qualquer formato que será usado na apresentação. Se fosse outro banco de dados que tem um formato de dado, ele não estaria em formato algum. No caso do SQLite você tem que cuidar disto na mão. Se tiver outras dificuldades para manipular a data, você vai colocando suas dúvidas específicas. Dado e formato de apresentação são coisas distintas. Grave no formato que precisa e adapte o dado sempre que for apresentá-lo.

Comment: Quem acha que tem alguma coisa errada, pode dizer o que?

Answer (score 0):

O SQLite não ordena as datas como os outros bancos, mysql por exemplo, eu também tive esse problema numa aplicação minha, mas resolvi usando o "compareTo" na classe do meu objeto.

Talvez não seja a solução que você precise.

Classe Call

```
public class Call{  
... 

/**      
* metodo para ordernar por data      
* @param another Call classe de entrada para comparar    
*/   
@Override    
public int compareTo(Call another) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");      
    java.util.Date dateComparer, dateActual;
    try {           
        dateActual = sdf.parse(this.getData());             
        dateComparer = sdf.parse(another.getData());

        if (dateActual.before(dateComparer)) {
            return Constants.SUCESS;
        }
        if (dateActual.after(dateComparer)) {
            return Constants.ERROR;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

depois eu crio uma lista e ordeno:

```
private List<Call> listCalls(ResultSet resultset){

  List<Call> calls = new ArrayList<Call>();
  do {
     Call item = new Call();
     item._id           = resultset.getString(Call.FIELD1); 
     calls.add(item);
  } while (resultset.next());  
  ...
  Collections.sort(calls);
}
```